# Laravel & Javascript - Converting Time to Todays Date + Time

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Im looking for help converting a Time only feild to dateTime so i can calculate "Time Elapsed"
For Sports events, I have a feild for Date & Time for the event/game, a feild for 1st half start time, and 2nd half start time, these last two do not include dates,

Example,
Event Date -  Wed Apr 28 2021 21:29:05 GMT+1200
1st Half - 21:17:22

How can i calculate the time elapsed from the current time to the start time of the 1st half?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could create a copy of the event date and set the time to the value of the 1st half, then calculate the difference from the two `DateTime` objects (or `Carbon` if that's what you're using).

Comment: Carbon is the library you need for your time-related operations